# decomposition of $\mathbb{C}[A_3],\mathbb{R}[A_3]$ and $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ into simple algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $A_3$ be the alternating group of three symbols (which is cyclic group of order 3).
I want to know how to write $\mathbb{C}[{A_3}],\mathbb{R}[{A_3}],\mathbb{F}_{p}[A_3]$ as a direct sum of decomposition into simple algebras.

My attempt:-
I think $\mathbb{C}[A_3]=\mathbb{C}\oplus \mathbb{C} \oplus \mathbb{C}$.

$\mathbb{R}[A_3]=\mathbb{R} \oplus \mathbb{C}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $F$ is any field, then $F[A_3]$ is $F[x]/(x^3 - 1)$. By the Chinese remainder theorem this decomposes as follows:

- If $F$ has characteristic $\neq 3$ and $x^2 + x + 1$ is irreducible over $F$, then $F[x]/(x^3 - 1) \cong F \times F[x]/(x^2 + x + 1)$.
- If $F$ has characteristic $\neq 3$ and $x^2 + x + 1$ is reducible over $F$, then $F[x]/(x^3 - 1) \cong F^3$.
- If $F$ has characteristic $3$, then $F[x]/(x^3 - 1) \cong F[x]/(x - 1)^3 \cong F[x]/x^3$.

In particular your answers are correct. More generally, CRT can be used to describe $F[G]$ where $G$ is a finite abelian group. The nonabelian case is harder.

Comment: Thanks I think this more general case help a lot, but it make me wonder if still we can apply ( or at least we have ) some similar argument for $\mathbb{C}[A_4]= \mathbb{C}\oplus  \mathbb{C}\oplus  \mathbb{C}\oplus M_{3}(\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: @henry: for nonabelian groups CRT is no longer available so we have to work harder. Over $\mathbb{C}$ this is the problem of computing the degrees of the complex irreducible representations of a group, which is a difficult problem in general, although lots is known about it. Over $\mathbb{R}$ you need the complex irreducible representations and their Frobenius-Schur indicators. Over other fields things get thorny, especially for characteristic dividing the order of the group.

Comment: again thanks.  this give me more insight about this topic even I am new to it.